# seeking replay media in gst-rtsp-server

Tags: video, gstreamer

I am bit uncertain over the passing of seek event to an rtsp-server server. Would need some advice

DESCRIPTION
I am trying to code for a  rtsp-server using gst-rtsp-server library which should help in replay of certain files(non-live source). I would require seeking function for the user to play the desired video segment.

I have two threads to do it. My replay thread is on one thread while my rtsp-server stream function is on another thread connected together via udp.  Is it possible that the seek event could reach the thread where my replay bin is in instead of passing through the rtsp-server. Or I have to handle it via some event passing mechanism, maybe beyond what gstreamer library provides